# Java debugging info not generated for Interfaces

Tags: debugging, javac, named-parameters

I'm trying to generate class files with the "-g:vars" option. This is working fine for classes and I get the parameter name as it is in the source. But this doesn't seem to be working for Interfaces.

e.g. Interface
public interface Test

```
{
    public abstract void doesntWork(String name, String last, int id);
}
```

=======Generates==========

```
//  (version 1.6 : 50.0, no super bit)
public abstract interface Test {

  // Method descriptor #4 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
  public abstract void doesntWork(java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1, int arg2);
}
```

while...

```
public class Test
{
    public void doesntWork(String name, String last, int id) {}
}
```

===========Generates (only relevant part shown)============

```
 public void doesntWork(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String last, int id);
    0  return
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: Test
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: name index: 1 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: last index: 2 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: id index: 3 type: int
```

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that Local variable table is not applicable to Interfaces.
How do I get the debugging info as it is for Interfaces too?

Answer (score -1):

Well, where are you going to see the parameter names from the interface? Every single implementing class will provide its own names—what's the point of storing interface's ones?

Comment: Agreed, but then shouldn't the "-g" debugging behavior be consistent over interfaces and classes alike. Ofcourse, the names could be overwritten in the implementing class.

Vote up requires 15 rep points. Can I know the downvoter by any chance?

Comment: It shouldn't: there's no way to use those names for debugging. Hence, no need to store those. It's not "*could* be overwritten"—it's "must and will be overwritten"

Comment: I'm the down-voter - sorry, thought it was obvious, which means I probably misread where you were coming from.  It seemed like a pointless "sour grapes" answer - if you can't have it, you must not want it anyway.  And there are lots of tool-ware applications where you'd want the names - generating subclasses, documenting tests, creating UML, etc.  And it's not an answer - it's a comment.

Comment: What if an IDE wants to show info on this decompiled interface, shouldn't this be allowed?